# setCompoundDrawables working only when drawable set to another imageview?

Tags: android

I am changing the color of a drawable and then setting it as drawable left of a textview, but i am observing a weird thing.
The drawable left is only working if i am setting the drawable to some other image view before setting it into the textview.

```
  Drawable mDrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.legendc);
                    mDrawable.setColorFilter(colorsActive[0], PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    mImageview.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);

                    mtextview.setCompoundDrawables(mDrawable, null, null, null);
```

If i remove  mImageview.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
then the setCompoundDrawables is not working and no drawable left is being applied.
Why is this happening??

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `setCompoundDrawables()` alone do not work might be something related to image rendering and creating references in Android. There is a parameter in every `Drawable` variable called `mCallback`. When you want to skip setting `ImageView` it's value is null, else it has a `WeakReference` variable - this means something like app would say *"Look, reference is bound to somewhere in the memory, now I can use it!"* Looks like `setImageDrawable()` method creates this binding, while `setCompoundDrawables()` doesn't.

I'm not an expert in this topic and what I've found is just a workaround (maybe you will need an `ImageLoader`-like object to handle this), but looks like using `mtextview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` works well.

```
//mImageview.setImageDrawable(mDrawable); You can delete this line

//Using this will not require to load your Drawable somewhere else
mtextview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mDrawable, null, null, null);
```